C# get EnvDTE.DTE interface of Visual Studio solution through instance of System.Diagnostics.Process
Context:
I'm currently writing an application that let's the user open a Visual Studio solution (.sln-file). They can then edit certain aspects of the opened project through the UI of my application rather than having to edit the code themselves. To avoid confusion I am talking about Visual Studio eventhough technically the file will be used and opened by TwinCatXAEShell, which is fundamentally the same thing.
Problem:
To open the solution file I use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(). However, to send commands to the running project I need a reference to the interface EnvDTE.DTE of that project.
Here is the code I use to open the file:
// get TwinCAT application
string applicationPath = getTwinCatInstallPath();
if (!File.Exists(applicationPath)) return;

// start TwinCAT with provided file
System.Diagnostics.Process fileopener = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
fileopener.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = applicationPath,
    Arguments = $"\"{solutionPath}\"",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
};
fileopener.Start();

Some "Solutions":
Option 1:
What I'm doing so far, is to search through the Windows running Object table and look for the processId in the runningObject's names. But I keep thinking it must be possible to access the instance of System.Diagnostics.Process directly...
Here is the code to search through the windows running object table:
(obviously not fully mine ^^)
static DTE ProcessToDte(System.Diagnostics.Process process)
{
    // get list of windows processes
    IRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable;
    GetRunningObjectTable(0, out runningObjectTable);

    // get enumerator for the list
    runningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out IEnumMoniker monikerEnumerator);
    monikerEnumerator.Reset();

    // iterate over list and crate a subset with fitting processes
    IMoniker[] monikers = new IMoniker[1];
    while (monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, IntPtr.Zero) == 0)
    {
        CreateBindCtx(0, out IBindCtx ctx);
        monikers[0].GetDisplayName(ctx, null, out string runningObjectName);
        if (!runningObjectName.Contains("TcXaeShell")) continue;
        if (runningObjectName.Contains(process.Id.ToString()))
        {
            runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikers[0], out object runningObjectData);
            DTE ide;
            try { ide = runningObjectData as DTE; } catch { continue; }
            return ide;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable rot); // needed for ProcessToDte()
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
static extern int CreateBindCtx(uint reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc); // needed for ProcessToDte()

Option 2:
I found that another way get around this, is to never even use System.Diagnostics.Process and instead open the solution file as shown below, but process.Start() seems much more convenient and easier to understand for future code reviews.
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("TcXaeShell.DTE.15.0");
if (t == null) return;
DTE dte;
dte = (DTE)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
dte.SuppressUI = false;
dte.MainWindow.Visible = true;
dte.MainWindow.WindowState = vsWindowState.vsWindowStateMinimize;
dte.UserControl = true;


So what's the problem with the solution 1? That's what I've been using for years. Starting with VS 2017, you can have multiple instances of VS installed. So the preferred way is to specify the full path to devenv.exe. Here's my article which does exactly this and in essence is the same as your solution 1. To avoid random errors, it implements timeouts and MessageFilter. My example of implemented MessageFilter

But doesn't it cost performance to search through all running windows processes? And couldn't it occur, that another process happens to contain the processID in its name and therefore this method would fail?

The performance was never the problem for me. It's just a few milliseconds at the application startup. Launching the devenv process takes much longer. Especially, when you load a large solution into it. Then you may experience various problems that I solved by timeouts and MessageFilter (when you have thousands of users, you may bet it happens). The chances that another process name contains "TcXaeShell" and the process ID are almost zero. My check is eben more strict than yours: Regex monikerRegex = new Regex(@"!VisualStudio.DTE\.\d+\.\d+\:" + processId, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Using a regex for that is a good idea actually. I might use it too. You're probably right that the performance impact is negligable. I still think it's weird though that there is no direct way.

Are you expect to improve the solution so that it can run without searching all the Windows objects using System. Diagnostics? Is there any reason using the EnvDTE.DTE interface?

@FeiXu Yes, I need the EnvDTE.DTE interface later. So I'm looking for a way to get EnvDTE.DTE from fileOpener without searching through all windows ojects.

If you want to a reference to the interface EnvDTE.DTE of the opening project, i see Solution.DTE in this doc.

@DouXu-MSFT: The doc you linked mentions two ways: solution path moniker and item moniker. The item moniker approach is used in OP's solution 1 and in my recommendation above. One thing to keep in mind. The solution path moniker is less reliable because it's not unique. You can have the same solution open in multiple VS instances at the same time.
